# How to apply specfic coupon in ubercart while creating an order from backend means admin pages

Tags: ubercart

I am using ubercart. I am facing two issues while creating an order from backend.

1.) How to add coupon codes on add order admin page ?
i need to add orders manually from backend but not able to apply coupon codes for discounts, there is only a feature to "add a line item" but not for coupon.
I think there should be a textbox to fill coupon code and apply button to apply it.

2.) If coupon is applied to manually created order then tax calculation should be done after coupon price deducted from subtotal.

Comment: it is showing their coupon discount in select list and a button next to it showing add line item when I selected coupon discount and clicked the button add line item it gave me a textbox to add an amount I added -5 and 5 $ are deducted from the amount.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.) How to add coupon codes on add order admin page ? i need to add orders manually from backend but not able to apply coupon codes for
>   discounts, there is only a feature to "add a line item" but not for
>   coupon. I think there should be a textbox to fill coupon code and
>   apply button to apply it.

If you want to apply a coupon code from the admin page. Use the uc_discounts_alt module that provides you three submodules(uc_discounts,codeless_discounts_field,product_price_alterer_field).
Enable the uc_discounts module it will provide you the textarea at the admin configuration page to apply the discount code.
1)Go to admin >> store >> orders >> create
2)Enter the customer information
3)It will open the create order screen as shown in the screenshot below

> 2.) If coupon is applied to manually created order then tax calculation should be done after coupon price deducted from subtotal.

Yes.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Naveen for your reply. But after using uc_discounts module, I am still unable to add coupon to an order in manually created order

Comment: I have specified the Example for D6 ? Are you using D7 ? I think it will be same for the d6 as well.